# How to Fix - Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#440 ▼ #items: [] }

Tags: php, laravel, database, referrals

I want to select users that have a referral username and role of  4 in the users table and store them in $refUser but am getting this error.
"Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#440 ▼ #items: [] }"

```
  $new_ref_user = $user->referal;
            $itr_cnt = 0;    

            while ($itr_cnt <= $ref_cnt-1)
            {
                $refUser = User::where('username', $new_ref_user)->where('role', 4)->get();
                dd($refUser);
                if(count($refUser) > 0)
                {
                    $ref = new ref;
                    $ref->user_id = $user->id;
                    $ref->username = $new_ref_user;
```

Please, what am doing wrong? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`dd` means "dump and die". You're not receiving an error, you're seeing the result of your `dd($refUser)` call. `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#440 ▼ #items: [] }` is an empty collection.

Rather than querying the database inside a loop, you can use one query to get all users at once, then loop through those users instead. I don't know where `$ref_cnt-1` is in your code and why you have a loop at all, but you can do something like this. Also, check the spelling. Should it be `referral` or is the var spelled incorrectly? And is `ref` the name of a model class? I would suggest going with the name `UserReferral` instead.

If `$user->referral` is an array:

```
User::whereIn('username', $user->referral)
    ->where('role', 4)
    ->get()
    ->each( function ($ref) use ($user) {
       $model = new UserReferral;
       $model->user_id = $user->id;
       $model->username = $ref->username;
       $model->save();
   });
```

If `$user->referral` is just a string (`username`):

```
$ref = User::where('username', $user->referral)->first();
if ($ref) {
    $model = new UserReferral;
    $model->user_id = $user->id;
    $model->username = $ref->username;
    $model->save();
}
```

Note that `$query->get()` returns a `Collection` and `$query->first()` returns the first matching row (in a model instance if using Eloquent).

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please mark the answer “accepted”?

Comment: @JobShork The best "thanks" is marking the answer "accepted"...